# Convert image to base64 works but bad

Tags: javascript, canvas, base64

I want convert a picture to base64. So, in the html i put a img and canvas with display:none

**html :**

```
<img style="display:none" id="imgDownload" />
<canvas style="display:none" id="myCanvas" />
```

and in the controller i do this :

**controller :**

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("imgDownload");
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = conf.storeUrl + '/' +$scope.fRoot.name + $scope.getFileWay() + value.name;
console.log(img);
ctx.drawImage(img, img.naturalHeight, img.naturalWidth);
var base64Img = c.toDataURL();
```

i get a base64 but it's not good...

see an example :

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAAxUlEQVR4nO3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQhfoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOA1v9QAATX68/0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=

you can test it [here](http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter).

and i tried giving a height and width to the canvas but the result is that :

> data:,

and it's the same thing for différents images, you have a idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to draw the image on the canvas before it has finished loading.
After setting `img.src`, it takes some time to load the image, so you have to wait until that has happened before you proceed.
You can use `img.onload` for that:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("imgDownload");
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.onload = function()
{
    console.log(img);
    ctx.drawImage(img, img.naturalHeight, img.naturalWidth);
    var base64Img = c.toDataURL();
};
img.src = conf.storeUrl + '/' +$scope.fRoot.name + $scope.getFileWay() + value.name;
```

Comment: i tried with the onload but the onload don't work...